# Firefox css issue in factory industrial website template

Tags: html, css, firefox

I would like to use [Factory industrial website template](http://w3layouts.com/demos/the_factory/web/), which is really nice, but it has one CSS issue in Firefox browser.
Slideshow isn't displayed as it should in Firefox, and this really bothers me. It works well in Chrome and IE 11.

I lost my patience trying to fix the issue and I need help. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Or please just point me in right direction.

HTML code:

```
<!--start-image-slider---->
        <div class="slider"  id="top">                       
            <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">                                             
                <div data-src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/slider1.jpg">  </div> 
                <div data-src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/slider2.jpg">  </div>
                <div data-src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/slider3.jpg">  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="holder">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>                          
        </div>
        <!--End-image-slider---->
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <!----End--imageslider----->
        <!----start-top-header----->
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="top-header">
                    <div class="top-search">
                        <form>
                            <input type="text"><input type="submit" value="" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
...
...
...
```

CSS code is:

```
    body{
    background: #FFF;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-image: url('../images/bg-pattern.jpg');
}

.wrap{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.top-search {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.camera_thumbs_wrap table, .camera_thumbs_wrap tbody, .camera_thumbs_wrap tfoot, .camera_thumbs_wrap thead, .camera_thumbs_wrap tr, .camera_thumbs_wrap th, .camera_thumbs_wrap td {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    list-style: none
}
.camera_wrap {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
.clear{clear:both;}/* clear float */
```

Comment: Since you say you've tried several things, what exactly have you tried? Share some code with us; help us help you.

Comment: A lot of combinations of position:relative,absoulute,etc; z-index:from -1 to 1, and inclunding margins etc... I just don't finx the right combination...
This is my second day trying to fix the problem and i'm losing my  nervs

Comment: If you could include the code related to the slideshow in your post, and maybe a JSFiddle, that would go a long way toward getting your problem solved; I don't think anyone is going to download and inspect a whole template just to help a stranger for free.

Comment: i just added a code, so problem is some where here

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: I founded a solution! I just had to make one another div around. Plase unhold the qustion so i can  publish the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!--start-image-slider---->
        <div class="slider"  id="top">                       
            <div class="camera_wrap camera_azure_skin" id="camera_wrap_1">                                             
                <div data-src="http://www.smd-sp.si/images/slider2.jpg">  </div>
                <div data-src="http://www.smd-sp.si/images/slider3.jpg">  </div>
                <div data-src="http://www.smd-sp.si/images/slider4.jpg">  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="holder">

            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>                          
        </div>
        <!--End-image-slider---->
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <!----End--imageslider----->
        <!----start-top-header----->

        <div class="divaround"> <!-- Here is the solutin div -->

            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="top-header">
                        <div class="top-search">
                            <form>
                                <input type="text"><input type="submit" value="" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"> </div>
                       ....
                       ....
        </div>
```